# where to see impact or user reached

Tags: discussion, feature-request

Where can we see the exact impact. I know on activity board it shows in approximates. Is there any other place where I can see exact impact or could we do see exact impact may be on click over approximate impact or in on hover it shows a help popover.

[image]

Any helps!

Comment: What do you mean by "exact impact"?

Comment: Something like 9450 rather than 9000~ which is exact value.

Comment: Oh. How would that be useful? Impact is a very faulty metric, and it's not really supposed to be accurate.

Comment: But when we more from 9000~ to 10000~, how do we that, how internally we calculate it?

Comment: The metric is defined here: [We're working on a new stat to help convey the reach of your posts here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/244534/162704)

Comment: Okay i guess that is my answer... You may post that help as answer or we may just close the question...

Answer (score 4):

Your profile's "people reached" is calculated by taking the total number of views on your questions, and questions you've answered where your answer meets certain criteria. ([The exact algorithm is explained here.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/244534/were-working-on-a-new-stat-to-help-convey-the-reach-of-your-posts-here)) It's fundamentally not an exact measurement, so the value displayed isn't exact either.